# I am new to computer, so I try to install LAMP in ubuntu 18.04. and this is my problem, please help the Masters

Tags: mysql, sockets

Enter password:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Does have any idea?

Comment: This question has some answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run#15039113

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions:

1. Specify "127.0.0.1" as the host instead of localhost, i.e. mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root instead of mysql -h localhost -u root.
2. In /etc/mysql/my.cnf
   Change socket to the location of your MemSQL socket file as socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock instead of default value, this is /var/lib/memsql/data/memsql.sock.